# Groupby or Transpose?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I got this data

```
    country                     report_date market_cap_usd
0   Australia                   6/3/2020    90758154576
1   Australia                   6/4/2020    91897977251
2   Australia                   6/5/2020    94558861975
3   Canada                      6/3/2020    42899754234
4   Canada                      6/4/2020    43597908706
5   Canada                      6/5/2020    45287016456
6   United States of America    6/3/2020    1.16679E+12
7   United States of America    6/4/2020    1.15709E+12
8   United States of America    6/5/2020    1.19652E+12
```

and want to turn it into:

```
report_date Australia Canada ....
6/3/2020 90758154576 42899754234 ...
6/4/2020 91897977251 43597908706 ...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can u include the code you have tried so far

Comment: @sushanth I have no idea bro...

Comment: You might want to be more specific about the transform you're looking for.  For example, adding a second line for 6/4/2020 would make it more clear.  In general, this transform is known as a pivot.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html);

```
# setting minimum example 
import pandas

data = pandas.DataFrame({'country': ['Australia', 'Australia', 'Canada', 'Canada'], 
              'report_data': ['6/3/2020', '6/4/2020', '6/3/2020', '6/4/2020'], 
              'market_cap_usd': [923740927, 92797294, 20387334, 392738092] 
             })
```

```
# pivot the table
data = data.pivot_table(index='report_data', columns='country')

# drop multi-index column 
data.columns = [col[1] for col in data.columns]
```

Output;

```
            Australia   Canada
report_data         
6/3/2020    923740927   20387334
6/4/2020    92797294    392738092
```